MIM error with cpanel when uploading a vue.js app
guys i trying to host my vue.js project on cpanel and when i upload the dist and open it on my browser it shows that (Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.)
but when i upload other projects it working clearly
i try to host my vue app and it doesn't work
